# Break an equally spaced long table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, tabularx

I've been using `tabularx` and `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}` to get two equally spaced columns with text aligned to the left. Example:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        die Kleidung & clothes \\
        der Schuh & shoe
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that if I create a long table, the content goes outside the bottom page margins, like this:
[image]
**How can I break this table automatically while keeping exactly the same alignment?**

I've tried using the packages `longtable`, `ltablex` and `ltxtable`, unsuccessfully. Whenever I get the break to work properly at the end of the page, the alignment does not. See below. [image]
However, this solution is still pretty bad... not only due to the alignment I can't fix, but also because it spoils all other `tabularx` tables. The next image shows how a table using `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y|Y|Y@{}}` becomes different. See how it changes below.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have the `xltabular` package. Its eponymous environment brings the functionalities of  `longtable`  to `tabularx` (with the syntax of longtable – `endhead`, `\endfirsthead` &c.)

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the welcome and the reply! I had to upload this `xltabular` package on Overleaf manually, but it worked perfectly. I have spent so much time trying to solve this problem and `xltabular` package solved it so easily. It seems I don't even need `tabularx` anymore. You are awesome, thank you! Please, add this as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: I don't think it is useful, there are already other answers mentioning it (including by me) but I don't remember where on this site. This package loads `tabularx`, but it has a slightly different syntax, due to the incorporation of features from long table. I believe that, just like long table, it does not float, so tabularx still has its usefulness for shorter tables

Comment: @Bernard I have opened a lot of stackexchange pages about it and none could help me, unfortunately. And I will keep what you said about tabularx in mind. Thank you again! BTW, how can this topic be closed as done/answered if I can't accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: No idea, but don't care, someone surely will know :-)